# ORDER BY Count(p.id) is it possible?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following query:

```
$queryBuilder = $em->createQueryBuilder()->select('s')
                ->from("MainBundle:Style", 's')
                ->select('DISTINCT s')
                ->leftJoin('s.pictureStyle', 'ps')
                ->leftJoin('ps.picture', 'p')
                ->leftJoin('p.category', 'pc');

        if ($category instanceof InstagramTopCategory)
        {
            $queryBuilder->leftJoin('pc.pictureTopCategory', 'category');
        }
        else if ($category instanceof InstagramFirstLevelCategory)
        {
            $queryBuilder->leftJoin('pc.pictureFirstLevelCategory', 'category');
        }
        else if ($category instanceof InstagramSecondLevelCategory)
        {
            $queryBuilder->leftJoin('pc.pictureSecondLevelCategory', 'category');
        }

        $query = $queryBuilder->where('category = :category')
                ->andWhere('p.isLocked = 0')
                ->andWhere('p.deletedAt IS NULL')
                ->orderBy('COUNT(p.id)', 'DESC')
                ->groupBy('ps.pictureStyle')
                ->setParameter('category', $category)
                ->setMaxResults(10)
                ->getQuery();
```

however in the order by, it doesn't gives me an error of:

```
 Error: Expected end of string, got '('
```

how is this possible? I wrote an equivalent query in MySQL using COUNT directly in orderBy and it worked just fine, is this an issue in doctrine?

**EDIT:**
100% sure it's the order by since if I remove the line the error goes away

Comment: Are you sure the error is coming from the orderby?  If you remove that line the error goes away?

Comment: @Tom yes if i remove the line the error goes away

Comment: I don't know anything about how Doctrine generates its SQL, but in actual SQL syntax, the `GROUP BY` would have to come before the `ORDER BY`. Have you tried moving your `->orderBy(...)` and `->groupBy(...)` into the normal order?

Comment: try to add that order by variable in fields list and use that variable in order by as below

`select count(p.id) as cnt`
use `order by cnt DESC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your query as follows

```
$queryBuilder = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('s')
    ->from("MainBundle:Style", 's')
    ->select('DISTINCT s')
    ->addSelect('COUNT(p.id) as HIDDEN c_id')
   [...]
    ->orderBy('c_id', 'DESC')
   [...]
```

Comment: this works but then it would return the count as well..so it would be an array of array.. how do I remove the count from being returned?

Comment: Well, unset it if you can't do anything else :)

Comment: Doctrine has HIDDEN so you can use `->addSelect('COUNT(p.id) as HIDDEN c_id')`.